# How can I show my addon in add-ons store?

Tags: google-apps-script-addon

I build google doc add-on for google doc files, as locally deploy its' working like charm but when i try to publish add-on by following this https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish so it's publish as chrome extension not as add-ons.
I just want to publish my add-ons to show in add-ons store as well it should show with all google doc files under add-ons menu, please see in image where i want to display my add-ons.
[image]

Comment: Clarify your question

Comment: please look at now and let me know if you want to know anything else about this question